# How to stop horizontal borders overlapping each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a few links that are stacked horizontal, and each of these have a border top and bottom, when I have one of these links I want that links top and bottom border to change to black. But at the moment they're overlapping and appearing to be thicker.. they should just remain as 1px and only change color. Any help appreciated.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/GRjKvRm)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
li:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul a {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving the `border-top` and `border-bottom`, we need to give `border-top` for all the elements and add `border-bottom` for the last element only.

Try the below CSS and let me know if it works for you.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
 
}
li:last-child{
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
li:hover,li:hover + li{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
li:last-child:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul a {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have applied border-top and border-bottom.
For the first element it will appear fine, the second element has border top which is collapsing with border-bottom of previous element.

To fix this just remove border-bottom from all the li elements
Add Border-bottom to last-child. This is the fixed code

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  
}
li:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

ul a {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Select every list item except the first one, and move them up by 1px:

```
li:not(:first-of-type){
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Then select the sibling of the list item hovered over, and change that list item's top border to black:

```
li:hover + li {
  border-top-color: black;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
li:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul a {
  color: black;
}

li:not(:first-of-type){
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li:hover + li {
  border-top-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
</ul>
```